# How to calculate network traffic by process on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I want to do something like this:

```
time my_application
```

But instead of `time` I want some utility that will measure the network traffic:

```
<some_network_tool> my_application
```

It should give some stats after `my_application` quits. I'm only interested in volumes (Kb, Mb, Gb) and not in contents.

Is there such an utility?

Answer (score 0):

## [NetHogs](http://raboof.github.io/nethogs/)

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down per protocol or per subnet, like most tools do, it groups bandwidth by process. NetHogs does not rely on a special kernel module to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunaltely, You have bunch of choices to do that, if you want:

1. Overall bandwidth - nload, bmon, slurm, bwm-ng, cbm, speedometer, netload
2. Overall bandwidth (batch style output) - vnstat, ifstat, dstat, collectl
3. Bandwidth per socket connection - iftop, iptraf, tcptrack, pktstat, netwatch, trafshow
4. Bandwidth per process - nethogs

source: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/